# "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to TextView"

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm having an issue compiling a bit of source code and I'm getting an error stating "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to TextView" I've attempted to look this up on both Google and StackOverflow and SO is only returning one (unanswered) result.

Can someone either point me in the right direction or give an example of how this issue can be resolved?

Much appreciated. 
 - Tim

I have two instances of this error on the following two lines:

```
beamMsg[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
beamMsg2[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
```

SOURCE:

```
   void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // only one message sent during the beam
    NdefMessage[] msg =  new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        msg[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
        // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
        beamMsg[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
        beamMsg2[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
    }}
```

Comment: beamMsg[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload())); Here getRecrods() is a function and you have getRecaords()[1]. You should be passing parameters to the function something like getRecords(1)

Comment: Using the method suggested: beamMsg2[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords(1).getPayload())) caused eclipse to generate two new errors on top of the two I'm already experiencing:

The method getRecords() in the type NdefMessage is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: are those beamMsg[i] really TextView? if so, cast it and then call .setText...

Comment: @TimSalter do you have method getecords(int value) in NdefMessage?

Comment: The NdefMessage is plaintext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to call setText() method on the object beamMsg[i] and the compiler says that beamMsg is a TextView and not TextView[] array. the same applies to beamMsg2

Comment: Excellent - that resolved the issues! One more thing... I'm getting two errors on the same lines stating: 
Cannot invoke getRecords(int) on the array type NdefMessage[] 

Same issue? (When I attempt to remove the [] it results in more errors

Comment: what you get if you try: NdefRecord[] records = msg[i].getRecords();

Comment: argh, getRecords() takes no parameters, remove int parameter

Comment: Removing int on the line: for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {


Causes 5 "i cannot be resolved to a variable issues"

Comment: Ok (That changes the errors to getRecords cannot be resolved or is not a field)